# Closing all active sessions

Tags: php, session

I'm running two different php applications/sessions at the same time (on the same page), which I need to close/kill upon user logout and then redirect a user to a login page. Would this be the right way of doing it? Thanks.

```
<?php

session_name('loginsystem');
session_name('chatsystem');
session_start();
$_SESSION = array(); 
session_unset();
session_destroy();

header("Location:http://localhost:8888/vtracker2/index.php");

exit();
```

?>

Comment: Your request will only ever have one session at a time. These named sessions are useful for multiple different requests with separate sessions.

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment here. Session calls are within both "applications", and I'm naming them differently in order to avoid any potential issues with session array data, given that variables I use in both apps are very similarly named. So, my initial question is, how do I make sure that both session names are killed at the same time once user hits the logout button. If I'm understanding you correctly, are you suggesting that I don't have to stipulate session_name in my logout script? In that case would session_start(); followed by session_destroy(); be all I need? Thanks.

Comment: how are you storing them under different names? You would just be using $_SESSION for session data. Do you mean you just have two keys under $_SESSION, one for each application?

Comment: instead of using the default PHPSESSID, I'm assigning each session a different name as per the example above. I also use different names for $_SESSION arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are nearly done, just do this

```
<?php

session_start();
session_destroy();

header("Location:http://localhost:8888/vtracker2/index.php");
exit(); 

?>
```

`session_destroy()` function unset all the session which are active.

Comment: thanks. just wanted to be sure session_destroy(); will take in consideration any session name I might have had set manually, because as per the PHP official help, I saw something about stating the session_name in case I've defined one...